# Having issues splitting strings when using the strsep function

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, strsep

I'm very new to C programming and was trying to split a string through it's delimiters using the `strsep` function.

When executing the code below i get this output:

```
Hostname ( teste-13-f8-04teste-13-fd-80) Hostname (teste-13-fd-80) Hostname (teste-13-fd-86) Hostname (teste-13-fd-90)
```

Why is the `AllHostName[0]` giving that output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void splitStrings(char splitString[] , char variable[][15]);

void splitStrings(char splitString[] , char variable[][15])
    {
        char *token, *str, *tofree;
        int i=0;
        tofree = str = strdup(splitString);
        while ((token = strsep(&str, ",")))
            {
                strcpy(variable[i], token);
                i++;
            }
    free(tofree);
    }

int main(){
            char HostName[] = " teste-13-f8-04,teste-13-fd-80,teste-13-fd-86,teste-13-fd-90";
            char AllHostName[32][15];
            splitStrings(HostName, AllHostName);
            printf(" Hostname (%s) Hostname (%s) Hostname (%s) Hostname (%s)\n" , AllHostName[0] , AllHostName[1],AllHostName[2],AllHostName[3]);
           }
```

After getting this error I've noticed that it's related to the size of the original string, if it's a smaller string this issue doesn't appear.

Comment: Consistent indentation would make your code much more readable.

Comment: Your `char AllHostName[32][15]` is too small, change that `15` into a higher number and use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli  Careful with `strncpy()`, though.  It perniciously doesn't guarantee a terminating `'\0'` either.

Comment: Do you *really* want that space at the beginning of the first string?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli what's the advantage of using strncpy() instead of strcpy() ?

Comment: @Termanly not overflowing the buffer you are writing to.

Comment: @Termanly "dis-advantage of using `strncpy()`: 1) Result is not always null character terminated. 2) Padding end of buffer is often not needed and time wasteful going from O(string length) --> O(buffer size).  Alternatives exist such as A) `snprintf() and B) first insuring destination buffer is ample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first token in

`char HostName[] = " teste-13-f8-04,teste-13-fd-80,teste-13-fd-86,teste-13-fd-90";`

is

`teste-13-f8-04`

which is 15 characters long and too long for the **16** character token (which includes a terminating `'\0'` character) to fit into any of the **15**-character elements of `char variable[][15]`.

The terminating `'\0'` character gets overwritten by the first character of the next token, causing the tokens to run together.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.
My issue was that i thought this statement char AllHostName[32][15]; meant that it had an array of 16 elements with each of them having 32 chars.